# Read from Unity Catalog And Write to Hive Metastore

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

We have just started using Unity Catalog (UC) in Databricks in our team and wanted to know if it is possible to read from tables in UC and to write to tables in Hive Metastore (HM). We have a datalake with bronze, silver and gold layers. Bronze and silver are in UC but gold is still in the HM. We want to read from UC silver and write to HM gold.

Is this possible...? Would we be able to configure the job cluster to perform this task..?